# Does the Standard Model of Particle Physics actually state that particles don't exist?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model

If so looks like it's slightly mis-named.

Heard many times - no particles, just vibrations or oscillations in quantum fields.

Comment: Where did you see this statement?

Comment: Heard it many times - no particles, just vibrations or osculations in quantum fields.

Comment: @MarioDrag : You should move/copy this statement into the question body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you understand as the meaning of the term "particle." A particle is generally considered as Wigner saw it: a dimensionless point traveling on a world line. This concept is a classical view of particles which does not correspond to our current understanding of fundamental physics. The study of particle physics started long before the advent of the current standard model of particle physics. At the beginning people still thought of fundamental particles as little objects. For this reason "particle physics" is a legacy term that still relates to the same field of study even if we understand now that the particles that are being studied is not the same concept anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Particles exist according to the plethora of experimental data gathered over the last hundred years, and tabulated with masses etc as seen in the [Particle Data Group.](https://pdg.lbl.gov/)

The [Standard Model,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) as its name says, is a mathematical model that at present fits well the plethora of this data, and has been up to now very good in predicting new data and observations.

The Quantum Field Theory  and the [Feynman diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram) used for calculating crossections , decays, etc to fit the observations and data, does use creation and annihilation operators on defined fields to do the mathematical job. For the model it is the fields that allow for the mathematical behavior  of the particles, but even within the model the particles are defined/exist.

Answer (score 1):

It's that particles aren't classical particles. They're excitations of an underlying quantum field, for which a description may not "sound like a particle", but it is what physics means when it says "elementary particle".

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. The standard model is based on fermions (quarks and leptons) and bosons (photon, W, Z, gluons, Higgs).

See the review of particle physics at https://pdg.lbl.gov/